# Eliminating repeats in a switch statement w/ Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, switch-statement, xcode7

In this small practice app I am building, the background is supposed to keep alternating colors every .25 seconds because it looks really cool. However because of the fact that I am using the "arc4random_uniform" function, it occasionally will pick the same case twice in a row, resulting in a long duration of the same color which I do not like. Any ideas on how to eliminate immediate repeats in these switch statements so that it does pick the same case twice in a row?

```
    switch arc4random_uniform(10) {
    case 0:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    case 1:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    case 2:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    case 3:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    case 4:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    case 5:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    case 6:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    case 7:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    case 8:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    case 9:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    case 10:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    default:
        self.backgroundImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    break;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eli's answer will work, but regenerating random numbers in a while loop is unnecessarily inefficient. Instead, if the current random number is the same as the previous, I recommend incrementing the random number using the remainder when divided by 10 and using that number in the switch statement so that the random operation isn't repeated unnecessarily, ex:

```
var prevNum:UInt32 = 0

func changeColor() {
    var randomNum = arc4random_uniform(10)
    if randomNum == prevNum {
        randomNum = (randomNum+1)%10
    }
    prevNum = randomNum

    // insert your switch statement here
}
```

Theoretically (although it's improbable in practice) Eli's code can cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me! I am having no repeats at all!! :)

Comment: The probability of it going beyond 2 iterations is 0.1% the probability of it going infinite iterations is mathematically 0.

Comment: @EliSadoff I said theoretically, not mathematically.

Comment: There's a neat parallel to hash table open addressing, and it could be `(x+C) mode N` for any `C mod N != 0`. Likewise, quadratic probing could be used, etc. The downside is that a human viewer could learn that white is likelier to follow black than other colours (example based on +1 mod N and OP color list).

Answer (score 1):

Try storing a variable with the previous value and before you enter the switch statement have a `while` statement where you do

```
var num = arc4random_uniform(10);
while(num == prev) {
  num = arc4random_uniform(10);
}
```

then go into your switch statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eli! So are you saying that I should put that before my switch statement starts and then use the prev variable to store the previous case #?

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a color cycle by creating an array and then shuffling it. This way, numbers cannot be repeated. Then you can go through the array and use every value once.

```
var numbers = [Int](0 ..< 10)

for i in 0 ..< 10
{
    let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    (numbers[i], numbers[j]) = (numbers[j], numbers[i])
}
```

To avoid repetitions when generating a new array, you can use

```
if numbers.first == oldNumbers.last
{
    numbers.remove(at: 0)
}
```